# Need to set border around PDAnnotationTextMarkup, Highlight text in PDF

Tags: scala, pdfbox

Desired Result:

[image]

How do I set border(red) to my PDAnnotationTextMarkup? Just need to work with AdobePDF mainly.

```scala
def addCoordinates(cord: List[Coordinates], page) : PDPage = {
val annotations = page.getAnnotations
val borderThick = new PDBorderStyleDictionary()
borderThick.setWidth(0.8.toFloat)
borderThick.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_SOLID)

cord.foreach {

val textM = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT)
textM.setBorderStyle(borderThick)
textM.setColor(yellow)
// Set rectange and quads
annotations.add(markup) // Need to set border to markup?

// Below code i was able to get red border with Square annotation.
// This is more kind of workaround, see two annotations in Adobe PDF (not user friendly.)
val aSquare = new PDAnnotationSquareCircle(PDAnnotationSquareCircle.SUB_TYPE_SQUARE)
aSquare.setColor(red); 
 // set rectange and quads
annotations.add(aSquare)
}
page
}
```

Comment: did you call constructAppearances() (see the AddAnnotations.java example) ? If yes, please share more of your code and your PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Unable to use             annotations.forEach(PDAnnotation::constructAppearances); in Scala, Can you please share some other example?

Comment: //      val aSquare = new PDAnnotationSquareCircle(PDAnnotationSquareCircle.SUB_TYPE_SQUARE)
//      aSquare.setColor(red);  
//      aSquare.setBorderStyle(borderThick);
//      aSquare.setRectangle(bounds)
//      annotations.add(aSquare)

This code works fine and shows border, borderStyle not applied to PDAnnotationTextMarkup

Comment: If `aSquare.constructAppearances()` isn't available, then maybe you're not using the latest version? What version are you using?

Comment: I am able to see border for square annotation with setColor and borderStyle wihout calling constructAppearances, I am using pdfbox-2.0.22. 

Workaround was

Unable to get border for with PDAnnotationTextMarkup, so I had PDAnnotationSquareCircle  with border at same postion.

Issue: Need border with PDAnnotationTextMarkup. 

Thanks a lot

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I have added more code, Please let me know if i have to use constructAppearance, how i can do that. I refereed to example, That didn't work for me in scala (maybe due to structure of my code, function addCord is called for each page and does not have document parent).

Comment: I think I misunderstood this from the beginning, I doubt that the highlight annotation supports borders at all, I can't remember having seen it. Do you have a PDF that has borders in it?